# Error: tipo incompatible en constructor, string cannot be converted to int

Tags: java

la solucion a mi problema debe ser una pavada pero no lo puedo ver. Estoy creando constructores con diferentes variables y constantes y uno de ellos tiene dos variables y dos constantes. Este me tira un error de compatibilidad que no entiendo por que sucede. Gracias por la ayuda.

```
package recursos;


public class Electrodomestico {
    private int precioBase;
    private String color;
    private char consumoEnergetico;
    private int peso;

    private static final int PRECIOBASE=100;
    private static final String COLOR="blanco";
    private static final char CONSUMO='F';
    private static final int PESO=5;

    public Electrodomestico(){
        this(PRECIOBASE, COLOR, CONSUMO, PESO);

    }
```

aca sucede el error.

```
    public Electrodomestico(int precioBase, int peso) {
        this(COLOR, CONSUMO);
        this.precioBase = precioBase;
        this.peso = peso;

    }


    public Electrodomestico(int precioBase, String color, char consumoEnergetico, int peso) {
        this.precioBase = precioBase;
        this.color = color;
        this.consumoEnergetico = consumoEnergetico;
        this.peso = peso;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Analicemos tus constructores y verás el problema:

El constructor "base" es éste:

```
public Electrodomestico(int precioBase, String color, char consumoEnergetico, int peso) {
    this.precioBase = precioBase;
    this.color = color;
    this.consumoEnergetico = consumoEnergetico;
    this.peso = peso;
}
```

Recibe 4 parámetros y los guarda, correcto

Luego tienes un constructor sin parámetros:

```
public Electrodomestico(){
    this(PRECIOBASE, COLOR, CONSUMO, PESO);
}
```

Éste delega en el anterior, pasándole 4 valores que serán los valores por defecto.

Por último tienes:

```
public Electrodomestico(int precioBase, int peso) {
    this(COLOR, CONSUMO); //???
    this.precioBase = precioBase;
    this.peso = peso;

}
```

Este constructor intenta delegar en otro que recibe dos parámetros: color (String) y peso (int), pero no tienes ningún constructor que cumpla esa firma, así que el compilador asume que es una llamada recursiva: éste es el único constructor con dos parámetros, pero no coinciden en el tipo y por lo tanto falla.

Asumo que lo que querías hacer era

```
public Electrodomestico(int precioBase, int peso) {
    this(precioBase, COLOR, CONSUMO, peso);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`COLOR` es de tipo `String` y `CONSUMO` de tipo `char` pero no tienes definido ningun constructor que reciba parametros de esos tipos.

O defines un constructor que reciba los tipos que deseas:

```
public Electrodomestico(String color, Char ch)
{
 ///
}
```

O envias los parámetros correctos a uno de los constructores que ya tienes definido.